# How to inject a string that contains ${...} in spring application.properites

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-config

How to inject a string that contains ${...} in spring application.properites

I wanted to provide following key value pair in the applicaiton.properties file in spring and wanted spring to ignore the place holder without resolving it.

```
output.folder=${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd}/success/${header.CamelFileName}
```

But while loading spring is trying to provide the place holder value, for instance header.CamelFileName and would throw exception. Is there any way this can be escaped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, to escape a placeholder:

```
$=$
output.folder=${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd}/success/${$}{header.CamelFileName}
```

It could look a little bit tricky, but you have to escape a dollar sign, in order not to turn a `${header.CamelFileName}` into reference